# How to stop js setInterval when DOM is removed in Vuejs 3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a component.vue file which houses an SVG. The animations for the SVG are defined inside the  tags of the file. The script code modifies the behavior of the different parts of SVG.

The problem is when the DOM is re-rendered (when I go to another router-link/Page). I start getting

`Uncaught ReferenceError: <SVG's part id> is not defined`

in the console. The animation code has `setInterval` usage. So there are infinite instances of error - unless I refresh the browser or move back to the page (which has the SVG DOM).

```js
export default {
  name: "JackHammer",

  mounted() {
    var funcs = [
      "load",
      "addEventListener",
      "daysLeft",
      "getElementById",
      "setInterval",
      "getTime",
      "getTimezoneOffset",
      "floor",
      "textContent",
    ];

    var daysLeft;
    var frameNumber = 0;
    var endDate = new Date(2021, 1, 20, 10, 0, 0, 0);

    window.addEventListener(
      "load",
      function () {
        initJackhammer();
      },
      false
    );
    function initJackhammer() {
      daysLeft = document.getElementById(funcs[2]);
      ShowTimeLeft();
      window.setInterval(ShowTimeLeft, 1000);

      var jackhammerTip = document.getElementById("jackhammerTip");
      var jackhammer = document.getElementById("jackhammer");
      var jackBody = document.getElementById("jackBody");
      var jackArms = document.getElementById("jackArms");
      setInterval(animateJackhammer, 40);
    }

    function ShowTimeLeft() {
      // if (!document.getElementById("hoursLeft")) {
      //   return;
      // }
      var CurrTime = new Date();
      var timeDiff = (endDate - CurrTime) / 1000;
      var timeDiffInDays = Math.floor(timeDiff / 86400);
      timeDiff -= timeDiffInDays * 86400;
      var TimeDiffHours = Math.floor(timeDiff / 3600) % 24;
      timeDiff -= TimeDiffHours * 3600;
      var TimeDiffMinutes = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60) % 60;
      timeDiff -= TimeDiffMinutes * 60;
      var TimeDiffSeconds = Math.floor(timeDiff % 60);
      daysLeft.textContent = timeDiffInDays;
      hoursLeft.textContent = TimeDiffHours;
      minutesLeft.textContent = TimeDiffMinutes;
      secondsLeft.textContent = TimeDiffSeconds;
    }

    function animateJackhammer() {
      // console.log(jackhammerTip)
      if (!document.getElementById("jackhammerTip")) {
        return;
      }

      frameNumber++;
      jackhammerTip.setAttribute(
        "transform",
        "translate(0," + (frameNumber % 3) * -3 + ")"
      );

      jackhammer.setAttribute(
        "transform",
        "translate(0," + -Math.sin(frameNumber * 1.5) + ")"
      );

      var jackBodyAmount = Math.sin(frameNumber) + 2;
      jackBody.setAttribute(
        "transform",
        "translate(0," + -jackBodyAmount + ")"
      );
      jackArms.setAttribute(
        "transform",
        "translate(0," + -jackBodyAmount + ")"
      );

      if (frameNumber == 1000) frameNumber = 0;
    }
  },
};
```

I am new to Vuejs and JS as a whole.
I want to JS code to suspend when the DOM is removed and again start when its rendered again. What can be the most optimized way to achieve this?

Currently, I am just exiting out of the functions if the DOM element does not exist. Would appreciate a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Assign your interval to a variable and then `ClearInterval(variable)` during the `beforeUnmount` step.

Eg.:

```js
let myInterval

[...]

mounted() {
  myInterval = setInterval(animateJackhammer, 40);
}

[...]

beforeUnmount(() => { 
  clearInterval(myInterval);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default {
  name: "JackHammer",
  data() {
     return {
        timer: null,
     }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
     clearInterval(this.timer);
  },
  mounted() {
    var funcs = [
      "load",
      "addEventListener",
      "daysLeft",
      "getElementById",
      "setInterval",
      "getTime",
      "getTimezoneOffset",
      "floor",
      "textContent",
    ];

    var daysLeft;
    var frameNumber = 0;
    var endDate = new Date(2021, 1, 20, 10, 0, 0, 0);

    window.addEventListener(
      "load",
      initJackhammer.bind(this),
      false
    );
    function initJackhammer() {
      daysLeft = document.getElementById(funcs[2]);
      ShowTimeLeft();
      window.setInterval(ShowTimeLeft, 1000);

      var jackhammerTip = document.getElementById("jackhammerTip");
      var jackhammer = document.getElementById("jackhammer");
      var jackBody = document.getElementById("jackBody");
      var jackArms = document.getElementById("jackArms");
      this.timer = setInterval(animateJackhammer, 40);
    }

    function ShowTimeLeft() {
      // if (!document.getElementById("hoursLeft")) {
      //   return;
      // }
      var CurrTime = new Date();
      var timeDiff = (endDate - CurrTime) / 1000;
      var timeDiffInDays = Math.floor(timeDiff / 86400);
      timeDiff -= timeDiffInDays * 86400;
      var TimeDiffHours = Math.floor(timeDiff / 3600) % 24;
      timeDiff -= TimeDiffHours * 3600;
      var TimeDiffMinutes = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60) % 60;
      timeDiff -= TimeDiffMinutes * 60;
      var TimeDiffSeconds = Math.floor(timeDiff % 60);
      daysLeft.textContent = timeDiffInDays;
      hoursLeft.textContent = TimeDiffHours;
      minutesLeft.textContent = TimeDiffMinutes;
      secondsLeft.textContent = TimeDiffSeconds;
    }

    function animateJackhammer() {
      // console.log(jackhammerTip)
      if (!document.getElementById("jackhammerTip")) {
        return;
      }

      frameNumber++;
      jackhammerTip.setAttribute(
        "transform",
        "translate(0," + (frameNumber % 3) * -3 + ")"
      );

      jackhammer.setAttribute(
        "transform",
        "translate(0," + -Math.sin(frameNumber * 1.5) + ")"
      );

      var jackBodyAmount = Math.sin(frameNumber) + 2;
      jackBody.setAttribute(
        "transform",
        "translate(0," + -jackBodyAmount + ")"
      );
      jackArms.setAttribute(
        "transform",
        "translate(0," + -jackBodyAmount + ")"
      );

      if (frameNumber == 1000) frameNumber = 0;
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: you should pass the context to the function which creates setInterval in order to save the timer somewhere on vm instance. then you should use beforeDestroy vue lifecycle hook to stop the function. This is not perfect decision, but probably the simplies.

Comment: `beforeDestroy` is a Vue 2 lifecycle hook. Vue 3 uses `beforeUnmount` but same idea.